# Как использовать библиотеку BioinfoFieldExtractor.UPGMA?

Tags: java

Мне нужна библиотека BioinfoFieldExtractor.UPGMA, но не понимаю, как ее подключить к проекту. Помогите разобраться с этим.

Вот ее описание: [UPGMA](http://autofuzz.sourceforge.net/javaDoc/BioinfoFieldExtractor/UPGMA.html)

Comment: Для чистой Java или для Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build path - add external lib

Comment: Глупый вопрос, конечно, но где ее можно скачать?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/autofuzz/